# Update Angular4 model after changed the value from jQuery val() function

Tags: jquery, angular, model

Hi I am new in angular and i am using angular 4 and jquery .I want to update my model after changed the value from jquery val() .
here is the scenario:
html:

```
<input id="p1"  name="totalno" type="text" [(ngModel)]="totalno" >
```

jquery:

click:

```
function () {

  $("#p1").prepend($('<li>'+''+''+this.lbl+''+''+'</li>').text()+',');
  $("#p1").val($("#p1").text());
  $("#p1").val();
  this.totalno = $("#p1").val();
}
```

how to  update model after changed the value from  val() function

Comment: Wrap the code in a setTimeout or use changeDetector. Or better, don't use jQuery

Comment: thanks for your comment David . But I have to get value from button click.is it possible to bind angular model  with jquery element????

Comment: why are you doing this concatenation `+''+''` ?

Comment: @user1220461, try to read the Angular documentation, and look to examples there. First you don't need `jQuery` at all with Angular, unless your are importing some legacy library which requires you. All variables binding, updating model etc. all done within the angular it self.

Comment: madalinivascu:  I am  creating id of all <li> dynamically  so I used  +''+'' in my code

Comment: As others have said, don't use jQuery. It's bad practice unless you use a specific library that does not have Angular equivalent. You should really read the Angular documentation and look up for examples.

Comment: thanks for your valuable comments but I am using third party jquery and I need to get some value from jqery val() function .it is my project requirement .

Comment: `setTimeout(()=>this.totalno = $("#p1").val())`

Comment: setTimeout(()=>this.totalno = $("#p1").val()) it is not working